# Cocos2d-X : how to run Cocos2d-X project (mac) developed with XCode on android device (eclipse)?

Tags: cocos2d-x

i have developed one demo app in cocos2d-x . It nicely runs on my cocos2d-x simulator (iPhone). Now i want to run this app on android device(using eclipse AVD or say my android device). i successfully setup all environment  as explained here http://www.raywenderlich.com/33750/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-getting-started. i also run one hello world demo on my android simulator using eclipse.

Now, what i want is to run my this existed cocosd-x project on Andriod device.How can i achieve this !? [i am on mac platform]

This is much like porting my cocos2d-x iPhone project to android  .

Any kind of help would be appreciated lot.

Answer (score 3):

- go to cocos2d-x directory (that you downloaded)
- run "create-android-project.sh" (follow the on screen instructions)
- Replace the "Classes" "Resources" directories in the newly created
  project directory with the ones you have in your XCode project.
- Add your cpp files to the proj.android/jni/Android.mk file.
- run "build_native.sh" in proj.android directory.
- Open Eclipse, Import your android project
- Link the cocos2d-x java project (this will be under cocos2d-x/platform/android/java)
- Run the project. (If you have your android phone connected to the machine with DEBUG over USB enabled). You should see the project launched on your phone.

Comment: i should go to cocos2dx directory through command line Terminal ?

Comment: @
GizmoThunder .. can u please explain this more briefly 
??

Comment: Great answer @GizmoThunder, I'll try this. I have one more Question, Is there any other way than this? If yes, then let's know..!

Comment: @GizmoThunder Thanks for your help .. and this link is also helpful 
http://gameit.ro/2011/08/creating-an-iphone-and-android-cocos2d-x-hybrid-project/

Comment: http://jpsarda.tumblr.com/post/26000816688/integrate-cocos2d-x-c-into-an-android-application